# Center fixed image in div

Tags: css, html, css-position, alignment

I've created a JSFiddle here:
http://jsfiddle.net/AsHW6/

What I'm attempting to do is get the down_arrow.png's centered in their containing divs. I was able to center the up_arrow.png's using auto margins. I'm using the fixed property to use them as footers, as I want them to be at the bottom of the div regardless of resolution.

My question is what is the best way to center a bottom fixed image within the width of its containing div?

Some code from the fiddle (I'm having trouble with the StackOverflow formatting):

```
    .scroll-arrow-down {
        position: fixed;
        bottom:0;
    }
```

I should add that I don't care about IE hacks/workarounds at all, this application will not be targeting IE in any way.
Any comments and answers are appreciated.

Comment: .name{
       position: fixed;
        bottom:0; left:50%; margin-left:- px; /* imgage width/2 */
}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you used fixed position it will be fixed to the viewport (which I don't think you want). Using absolute positioning will position the images in reference to the item that contains them.

I added a left:45%; which pretty much centers things, but depending on the width of your arrows that may need to be updated.

```
.scroll-arrow-down {
    position: absolute;
    bottom:0;
    left: 45%;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/AsHW6/1/

Answer (score 1):

You can wrap the arrow-down images in a div that gets aligned to the bottom. The div can then be set to have its content centered.

Wrapping in HTML:

```
<div id="list1">
  <img src="image/up_arrow.png" class="scroll-arrow-up">
  <p class="list-title" id="list-title1">Autonomous Behaviors</p>
  <div class=".scroll-arrow-down">
    <img src="image/down_arrow.png">
  </div>
</div>
```

and the css:

```
.scroll-arrow-down {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  background-color: red;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}
```